# How to put a middle Grid item from 3 items to down, and the first and the third items to top?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 3 Grid items in my Grid container. I want in small(sm) size show the first and the last items in one line, and the middle item in the bottom. Here are pictures in common case.
[image: Common case]

In small size(less than 960px), I want to show the name and avatar and the price in one line, and the auto and time in second line in full width. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Hidden` component for that to hide parts on certain screensizes. Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x64ij